# Error inflating class ImageView caused by NumberFormatException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-compatibility

I recently got this weird error from a Android 4.2 device when inflating a `Spinner` item in the `getView()` method of its `ArrayAdapter`:

```
07-27 10:44:18.120 23988-23988/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: xxx.xxx.xxx, PID: 23988
                                                   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:17832)
                                                       at xxx.xxx.xxx.adapters.SpinnerAdapter.getView(SpinnerAdapter.java:37)
                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2338)
                                                       at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView.obtainView(ListPopupWindow.java:1605)
                                                       at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1273)
                                                       at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1176)
                                                       at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:554)
                                                       at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1106)
                                                       at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:980)
                                                       at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:962)
                                                       at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:285)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/color/tertiary_text_light.xml"
                                                       at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
                                                       at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:122)
                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:255)
                                                       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:155)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1008)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1067)
                                                       at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:17832) 
                                                       at xxx.xxx.xxx.adapters.SpinnerAdapter.getView(SpinnerAdapter.java:37) 
                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2338) 
                                                       at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView.obtainView(ListPopupWindow.java:1605) 
                                                       at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1273) 
                                                       at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1176) 
                                                       at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:554) 
                                                       at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1106) 
                                                       at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:980) 
                                                       at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:962) 
                                                       at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:285) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the XML of the item's layout:

```
<!-- item_autocomplete.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_autocomplete_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_autocomplete_img"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/item_autocomplete_title"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_18dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_autocomplete_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_autocomplete_img"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_autocomplete_img"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_autocomplete_img"
        android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the line where it crashed:

```
    // SpinnerAdapter.java
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(getContext(), RESOURCE, null); <-- Crash
        }
        ...
    }
```

So, what's wrong here? Android Studio does not throw me any warning and the app compiles and runs just fine on all devices I have tested...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is just that `android:tint=""` is to be assigned a color, not a selector, which `@android:color/tertiary_text_light` is.

Using directly its value `#808080` or through a resource value en `colors.xml` will work `@colors/gray_light`.

Comment: Can't do it untill 2 days from posting the question :(

Answer (score 2):

ImageView's tint is introduced in Android API 21. If you want to use it below API 21 you can use android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView and if you declare the tint as selector in xml you should replace "android:tint" with "app:tint" in the xml

Here is an example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_apply"
        app:tint="@color/button_selector" />
```